# When to use ../ vs ./ in Node.js require()

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

var User = require('../models/user');

So In Visual studio, I created a folder called models, and a file inside it called user.js . From what I learned it would make sense to put ./models/user instead of the two dots. Although, that gives me a crash, I was wondering what could be the reason for that. Thank you

Comment: I don't get the downvote, but sure...

Comment: you are inside user.js file and trying to import same file?

Comment: no.. I could be in any file, let's say app.js , trying to access user.js  that is inside of models... why would you assume that?

Comment: Do you already understand the different between `.` and `..`, and are just asking why you need to move up a level with `..` when your `app.js` is already at the project root?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand the difference. I've been blindly using one dot to access a file inside of a folder. It's worked MOST of the time.

Comment: nevermind kind sir, it has been answered

Comment: In case it will help you in writing future questions, you probably got downvotes because (1) it's not clear if you already know the general difference between `.` and `..` (as you just now clarified in your response) and (2) it wasn't clear where the file you're running is. If you made your project structure explicit, say which file you're running the `require` in, and explain that you're unclear the difference between `.` and `..`, you might not have gotten the downvotes (but I can't say for sure). Anyway, I'm glad you got a good answer. :)

Comment: Thanks mate! Noted :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.` (one dot) is the **current** directory

`..` (two dots) is the **parent** directory

Whichever one you use depends on what do you want to load.

Example:

Let's say that you have those file structure:

```
- app
  - dir1
    - file1.js
    - file2.js
  - dir2
    - file3.js
```

To use file2.js from file1.js you need:

```
require('./file2.js');
```

because those files are in the same directory.

But to use file3.js from file1.js you need:

```
require('../dir2/file3.js');
```

because you need to start from one directory up than the current one.

Of course to use file2.js from file1.js this would also work:

```
require('../dir1/file2.js');
```

or even this:

```
require('../../app/dir1/file2.js');
```

or even a crazy path like this:

```
require('./././../../app/../app/../app/dir1/file2.js');
```

This is not Node.js specific. It works the same as it would do in the shell or in HTML or anything. One dot is the current dir, two dots is the parent dir.

That's why you use `./script` to run the `script` in the current directory (if `.` is not in your PATH) and you would run `../script` to run the `script` in the parent directory etc. In HTML `<a href=".."></a>` would be a link to a parent directory, `<a href="../file.html"></a>` would be a link to `file.html` in the parent directory, while `<a href="./file.html"></a>` would be a link to `file.html` in the current directory etc. This is a pretty universal convention.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very clear explanation. Your last statement explains the down-votes aha.